# In the exam class, is there a way to keep questions on one page?

Tags: exam

Using an exam class, Is there a way to keep questions on one page.  Particularly with multiple choice questions, is there a way to keep a page break from occurring in the middle of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put questions in individual `figure`s. There are many other choices such as `table` or `minipage`. The advantage of the first two is that you would have a list of questions. Just simply `\def\figurename{Question}\listoffigures`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \lipsum[1] \par (A) \par (B) \par (C) \par (D)
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \lipsum[2] \par (A) \par (B) \par (C) \par (D)
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \lipsum[3] \par (A) \par (B) \par (C) \par (D)
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \lipsum[4] \par (A) \par (B) \par (C) \par (D)
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \lipsum[5] \par (A) \par (B) \par (C) \par (D)
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \lipsum[6] \par (A) \par (B) \par (C) \par (D)
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \lipsum[7] \par (A) \par (B) \par (C) \par (D)
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \lipsum[8] \par (A) \par (B) \par (C) \par (D)
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \lipsum[9] \par (A) \par (B) \par (C) \par (D)
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```